# add data to my data member

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

Hello I'm new to iPhone development.
I try to add move data from NSDictionary to data member of calls that i created.
When i "setWeightMeasure" nothing happened.

any suggestions?

the code that don't work:

```
NSDictionary *responseBodyProfile = [responseBody objectFromJSONString];
NSLog(@"%@",responseBodyProfile);
// the output is : 
"{ "profile": {"goal_weight_kg": "77.0000", "height_cm": "179.00", 
  "height_measure": "Cm", "last_weight_date_int": "15452", 
   "last_weight_kg": "99.0000", "weight_measure": "Kg" }}""

[responseBody release];

if (responseBodyProfile != nil ){
    NSDictionary *profile =[responseBodyProfile valueForKey:@"profile"];

    NSLog(@"%@\n",[profile objectForKey:@"weight_measure"]);// Output : "kg"

    [self.myUser setWeightMeasure:[profile objectForKey:@"weight_measure"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.myUser WeightMeasure]); // Output : "(null)"
 }
```

the H file properyty:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UserData* myUser;
```

UserData.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UserData : NSObject{
    NSString* Weight;
    NSString* Height;
    NSString* GolWeight;
    NSString* WeightMeasure;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Weight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* Height;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* GolWeight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* WeightMeasure; 

@end
```

UserData.m

```
#import "UserData.h"

@implementation UserData
@synthesize Weight, Height, GolWeight, WeightMeasure;

-(id)init{
    self.Weight = @"0";
    self.Height = @"0";
    self.GolWeight = @"0";
    self.WeightMeasure = @"0";
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [Weight release];
    [Height release];
    [GolWeight release];   
    [WeightMeasure release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: First of all, when you are creating/initializing your myUser object. can you just  NSLog(@"%@", self.myUser.WeightMeasure); And i do not like when the people do not follow the proper code guidelines. Do not you think your all member variable should start with small letter, well that does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use valueForKey instead of objectForKey in this line:

```
[self.myUser setWeightMeasure:[profile objectForKey:@"weight_measure"]];
```

like this:

```
[self.myUser setWeightMeasure:[profile valueForKey:@"weight_measure"]];
```

You might also want to use, since the values could be read as NSNumbers

```
[self.myUser setWeightMeasure:[[profile valueForKey:@"weight_measure"] stringValue]];
```

And why do you use strings instead of floats? Wouldn't that make your life easier when you'd need to perform some comparisons?

Also check if you have allocated memory for "myUser", that might be the case as well.

Comment: I choose string because "weight_measure" could be "Kg" or "lbs", so NSNumbers not relevant.
As i mentioned on the other answer, change "objectForKey" to "valueForKey", didn't solved my issue.

Comment: Okay, then the answer is obvious. You do not allocate memory for myUser property. If you are using it in the UIViewController subclass add this to your -viewDidLoad call: `self.myUser = [[UserData alloc] init];` If you are using any other type of class add that line of code into its initialization call.

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene mentioned, you should use valueForKey instead of objectForKey

The other thing is you might wanna use property and dot notation whenever you reference your object members, as Apple recommend. It is generally good for you to manage memory.

The previous answer about not initialize your string members in your -init() was totally wrong, if that cause some confusion, I do apologize for it.

Comment: Yes, but since it is already pointing to a string, which is @"0", he cannot make it point to another string.

Comment: Yes he can. Thats the whole point of pointers. Also there aren't such methods as valueOfKey and objectOfKey...

Comment: Sorry, mistyped, objectForKey

Comment: Yes you are right, he's just point to another string, which is right. My bad. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: 10x for the quick answer. i have in my h file the property: "@property (nonatomic, retain) UserData* myUser;"

Comment: In addition, I change valueForKey to objectForKey, and the output is still (null)